# Why for some values im getting an error but for others im not?

Tags: java, methods

I'm trying to create a method which takes a number inputted by the user, tests whether each digit in the number is odd, then returns true if all are odd and false if all are even. Heres the code.

```
    public static boolean allDigitsOdd(int num){

    int digits[] = new int[10];
    int numDigits = 0;
    String numTemp = Integer.toString(num);

    while(num > 1){
        num = num/10;
        numDigits++;
    }
    numDigits++;

    for(int i = 0; i < numDigits; i++){
        digits[i] = numTemp.charAt(i) - '0';
        System.out.println(digits[i]);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < numDigits; i++){
        if(digits[i] % 2 == 0){
            return(false);
        }
        if(i == numDigits){
            return(true);
        }
    }
    return(true);
}
```

When I enter '1234' or '1357', it works great and returns the right boolean but when I type almost anything else, it gives me a 'String index out of range' error at

```
    digits[1] = numTemp.charAt(i) - '0';
```

Comment: You might want to check for negative numbers?

Comment: What if there is a mixture of odd and even? what must it return?

Answer (score 1):

Change `while(num > 1)` to `while(num >= 10)`.

Otherwise, it will work only for numbers that start with 1 (such as 1234 and 1357), since for numbers that start with 2 to 9 (such as 9436534 or 4334), your calculation of `numDigits` will be too high by one, leading to 'String index out of range'.

It would be even better to forget about `numDigits` and just use `numTemp.length()` instead.

Comment: Instead of while loop, Jason can use numTemp.length()

Comment: @VimalBera My memory betrayed me. I was sure that String has a size() method and not length(). :) Thanks!

Comment: haha @Eran. The same was happening with me then I found way to remember. String can always be measured in length like centimeter, meter etc etc. Hope this helps you :D

Comment: @VimalBera Well, there's no need to remember these days. Eclipse or your IDE of choice remembers for you :)

Comment: Not now, but may be in some sort of quiz ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this another way.

Instead of turning your number into a String (which could give you scientific notation values and/or thousands delimiters, etc.) chop off the last digit and divide by 10 to give you a new number, like so (with recursion!):

```
public static boolean allDigitsOdd(int num){

    if (num < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("num must be 0 or positive");
    }

    if (num < 10) { // for 0-9, this is easy 
        return (num % 2 != 0); // if it isn't even, it's odd
    } else { // here comes the fun part
       int lastDigit = num % 10; // % is the remainder operation, not the modulo operation
       int newNum = num / 10; // because this is how ints work, this chops off the last digit
       return (lastDigit % 2 != 0) && allDigitsOdd(newNum); // recursion fun!
       // This will only return true if all of the tested digits are odd;
       // If there is just one even digit, the && operator returns false
    }
}

System.out.println(allDigitsOdd(1242)); // false
System.out.println(allDigitsOdd(73335799)); // true
```

You could do this with binary operators, but that just makes it less readable and not that much faster.

Answer (score 0):

You could even put all the stuff into a simple loop:

```
public static boolean allDigitsOdd(int num)
{
    while(num != 0)
    {
        if(num % 2 == 0)
            return false; // last digit is even
        num /= 10; // cut of last digit and repeat
    }
    return true; // all digits were odd
}
```

This will even work for negative numbers!